# Plotting overlapping sets of filled contours with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot superposed contour plots (normal distributions plotted against KDEs). I've gotten to the point of creating the contours, but I am stuck on allowing them to overlap. Ideally what I want is plot areas varying smoothly from near-transparent to highly opaque, colored by sample. I believe I can do this if I can fill each contour to the same `alpha` level, but I can't debug this easily: is it possible to access the underlying artists for a `QuadContourSet`? Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the relevant code:

```
for sample in samples:
    x = data[sample.id]

    # Plot probability density function
    res = sample.res
    T = res.params[0]
    s = res.bse[0]

    # Peform the kernel density estimate
    xx, yy = N.mgrid[x.min():x.max():1000j, -3*s:3*s:1000j]
    yy += T

    kernel = gaussian_kde(x)
    P = norm.pdf(yy.ravel(),T,s)
    v = kernel(xx.ravel())*P
    f = N.reshape(v, xx.shape)

    cset = comp_ax.contour(xx, yy, f,colors=sample.color, alpha=0.5)
```

I've played around with `contourf` as well (especially using a custom colormap from transparent to the desired color), but that has led nowhere. Any advice on this approach would be welcome as well.

Here's where I am right now (apologies for the bad layout hygiene)...

[image: Non-filled contours]